# Data Loss error when running schema compare with SSDT with Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

I am comparing a SQLServer2008 SP2 local DB with an Azure SQL Database, using the current SSDT version, in VS2012. I am getting:

```
    Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur
```

It wants to change:

```
    CONSTRAINT [PK_aspnet_UsersInRoles] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC, [UserId]
```

to:

```
    CONSTRAINT [PK_aspnet_UsersInRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC, [UserId] ASC),
```

ie change the PK to clustered. I have noticed that SQL Databases require indexes to be clustered, so I may need to change all of my local indexes to clustered, before deploying.

How do I get around this please?

Comment: What do you mean "SQL databases require indexes to be clustered"?  I am not aware of any such limitation in SQL Server.

Comment: I came across something that said that AZURE PKs need to be clustered. Also when I originally migrated the table using SQLAzureMW, my PK became clustered once on AZURE SQL Database, as in the code above. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think these issues are also to do with trying to deploy ASP.NET Membership tables across from SQL Server 2008 SP2 to Azure SQL Database and hitting some limitations that the original table setup uses. I have since found out SQLAzureMW made the PK clustered as part of its migration process.

Comment: . . There is a big difference between "SQL databases require indexes to be clustered" and "Azure databases require a clustered index".

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I do mean the Azure "SQL Database" service. I think they used to be called SQL Azure.

Comment: This all went away when I used MS's tweaked scripts for creating membership tables on Azure. They have to be different to what one would normally create in pureplay SQL Server.